# How to add a war build to a distribution

Tags: gradle, war

We have a gradle project that does a distTar to create a tar distribution file.
Each dependency project builds good placing all the dependencies and project jar files into the distribution libs folder.

We need to add a project that builds a war file. By adding the project as a dependency it adds all the war dependencies ... we need just the war file from the project war task.
Also the war project war task is not being executed.
Instead the jar task is being executed from distTar of the distribution project.

How do we execute the project war task and add just the war file to a "gui" folder in the tar distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a dependency to the output of the `war` task. By default, `ProjectDependency` simply adds a dependency to the default configuration of that project.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':myproject').war.outputs.files
}
```

**Edit**: To clarify, `compile` probably isn't the best configuration to add this dependency to, this is just an example. If indeed all this project is doing is aggregating dependencies into a single distribution archive then the configuration is likely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Mark this is what I needed. Your right about the compile config. The distribution also contains scripts that contain a classpath of the dependencies which I use named configs to control the classpath order. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: I've tried your answer but it fails on war not being a property of the project. It does not like it as a method either. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: For some odd reason there is no visibility to the .war.outputs.files unless wrapped in a doLast for a task see answer for solution that worked

Comment: It might be the project evaluation order. Perhaps that project hasn't had the `war` plugin applied yet. Just for grins, ty adding `evaluationDependsOn ':myproject'` the the dependent project.

Comment: It appears to be the case. A `war` plugin is not applied on the distribution project so it makes sense now that the `war.outputs.files` were not visible until the `dependsOn ':OtherProject:war'` executed requiring the `doLast`. Is the `evaluationDependsOn ':OtherProject'` the proper way over doing `doLast` in my solution? For your continued support I'm giving you the answer but my solution had the 'add to "gui" folder of distibution' answer ... can I get an up :) ... again thanks

Comment: The results are effectively the same. Using the dependencies method I use above results in an *implicit* dependency to the other project's `war` task, whereas your solution is an *explicit* dependency.

Answer (score 1):

To get the built war file into the distribution add a task which the distTar depends. Have the depends on task depend on the other project war task. Take the output files and put them in the distribution. The key is to do the into/from in a doLast so the depends on other project war completes before the into/from for the distribution.

```
// create a task depends on other project war
// put into the distribution gui folder the war.output.files
// the doLast gives visibility to the war.outputs.files
// after the depends on is complete
task otherProjectWar(dependsOn: ':OtherProject:war') {
  doLast {
    applicationDistribution.into("gui") {
      from( project(':OtherProject').war.outputs.files )
    }
  }
}

// add depends on for distTar
distTar {
  dependsOn otherProjectWar
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper approach is to include desired task outputs to the distribution. Here is sample script that adds jar built by the project to the main distribution (for war use war outputs instead of jar outputs).

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from jar.outputs
        }
    }
}
```

Running the distribution task then correctly resolves dependencies for both zip and tar.

```
> gradlew distTar
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes
:jar
:distTar
```

Comment: Documentation on the [distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html).

Comment: yes it is in-line with the documentation, that is why I added it here